# Same Variable prints all the contents in its list outside the loop but inside the loop it only prints the last appended value. WHy?

Tags: python, django

The Question is self-explanatory. The variable is reply_list.

```
def db_query():

    chat_data = {}
    queries = A.objects.filter(is_responded = 0)
    for query in queries:
        replies = []
        c_id = query.conversation_id
        b_ids = json.loads(query.sent_to)
        b_ids = b_ids["business_ids"]

        for index in range(len(b_ids)):
            b_ids[index] = int(b_ids[index])

        for b_id in b_ids:

            representative_reply = B.objects.filter(conversation_id = c_id , b_id = b_id)
            user_reply = A.objects.filter(conversation_id = c_id)
            replies.append(chain(representative_reply , user_reply))
            reply_list =[]
            for reply in replies:
                for r in reply:
                    reply_list.append(r.u_query)

            print reply_list               # prints the complete list. But when inside the loop , prints only the last appended value..........SEE DOWN........
            business_data = C.objects.filter(b_id = b_id)

            for data in business_data:
                print reply_list              # prints only the last appended value .... Why?
```

What I want is that the complete reply_list should be printed inside the `business_data` loop.

Any suggestions please. Where I am going wrong.

Comment: put a print statement in between            replies.append(chain(representative_reply , user_reply))
reply_list =[]

Comment: I guess, It will show an error saying `the variable is referenced before its assignment`. Still giving it a shot.

Comment: exactly the same error what I said. Any suggestions Plz.

Comment: Well what error are you getting?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary--- Can you please be a little more Descriptive????
Thanks

Comment: It is itertools.chain. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do I print 'reply_list' inside the `business_data` loop?

Comment: Is indentation proper?

Comment: The error is elsewhere, even if I don't know where.  A print of a list object can only print the whole list.  What if you put the line `print reply_list` twice?

Comment: @ArminRigo- It prints the last appended variable twice. Any thing else please.

Comment: @rajpy - Yes , it is. Any suggestion  ?

Comment: @rajpy - And I guess, indentation shouldnt really matters because its the same variable that I'm printing inside and outside the loop, so same contents should be printed.

Comment: Sometimes editor misleads you, I faced such a problem. I was thinking "for data in business_data" is actually outside main for loop the "for b_id in b_ids:" and reply_list could have only one value at last and that is getting printed. Lot of assumption:).